# Adding Images using Front-end form using Forminator and ACF

Tags: wordpress, frontend, advanced-custom-fields

i am trying to add user submission post page in the frontend and i'm using a form built in Forminator which contains Text Fields, Select fields, and image upload field, i was able to pass the inputted information from the form to the Post successfully using Advanced Custom Field plugin along with Post Data Field in forminator, the problem is when i upload an image using the form, it doesn't reflect in the image gallery.

to be more clear here is what i am trying to achieve.

This is the Forminator Fields

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb8Wk.jpg)

and this is post Data Field mapped Correctly to image upload field in ACF

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esLYC.jpg)

and here is the ACF Field Groups

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4El.jpg)

and that's the end result i get,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dVP5.jpg)

i did understand that Forminator Sends the images as URL, but the ACF Should expect Image ID or Attachment ID. How Can i get this Done Correctly?